# Replying a specific number through Twilio

Tags: python, python-3.x, twilio, twilio-api

I have multiple mobile numbers. I would like to detect an incoming message and respond only to the number that sent me a message.

Is there any chance this can be done using a single webhook, if yes how? Please let me know your suggestions.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import Message, MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/twilio", methods=["POST"])
def inbound_sms():
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    inbound_message = request.form.get("Body")
    if inbound_message.lower() == "hello":
        resp.message('Hello')

    else:
        resp.message("Hi! Not quite sure what you meant.\nText Hello to see all options.")

    return str(resp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Did you try to configure your "multiple mobile numbers" with the same webhook? What code did you try for the webhook?

Comment: @AlexBaban
Added code in the question.

Comment: The code should work for any of the numbers, so I think you can try and set them all to the same webhook.